# Does SSKeychain sync passwords across devices?

Tags: ios, keychain, sskeychain

I have to implement a UDID-like string for my application.
Therefore I used [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) to make a unique ID for my app and saved it to keychain with SSKeychain, in case it is changed each time the user reinstalls my application.

For each time I have to use the identifier, I will check in keychain whether if it's existed or I create and save one:

```
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{
    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:self.appName account:@"myapp"];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
    {

        strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:self.appName account:@"myapp"];
    }
    
    return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

I'm just afraid that the ID will be synced across user's devices then it couldn't be "UDID-like" anymore.
I wonder if this is a good practice for my app?

Comment: Have you found answer for this? Thanks